# Why AF and SF not set?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64

I'm reading Duntemann's book (3rd edition) and have just started learning x86 assembly. I'm using a variant of Fedora 23 (64 bit). The following is the code:

```
section .data
section .text
    global  _start
_start:
    nop
; Put your experiments between the two nops...
    mov eax,0FFFFFFFFh
    mov ebx,02Dh
    dec ebx
    inc eax 
; Put your experiments between the two nops...
    nop
```

My makefile is as follows:

```
sandbox: sandbox.o
    ld -o sandbox sandbox.o -melf_i386
sandbox.o: sandbox.asm
    nasm -f elf -g -F stabs sandbox.asm -l sandbox.lst
```

So you can see I've taken care to assemble a 32bit executable and not 64bit. The problem, however, is that prior to `dec ebx` instruction the `AF` and `SF` flag is not set contrary to what the book claimed. Running the program in `insight` shows me 32 bit registers which further assures the executable is 32bit. The following is status shown by `gdb` just before `dec ebx` instruction.

```
(gdb) info reg
eax            0xffffffff   -1
ecx            0x0  0
edx            0x0  0
ebx            0x2d 45
esp            0xffffce80   0xffffce80
ebp            0x0  0x0
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x804806b    0x804806b <_start+11>
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
cs             0x23 35
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x2b 43
es             0x2b 43
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

Duntemann's version in Pg 217 shows that `AF` and `SF` flag is set. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `mov`s don't set flags. Google for "intel manual 2" for an official document with instructions and flags affected by them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Margaret Bloom commented, the `mov` instruction does *not* set the flags! In fact, it has absolutely no effect on the flags whatsoever, which makes it very useful in cases where you want to set the contents of a register or memory without clobbering the current state of the flags.

This is documented in [the official Intel IA-32 ISA reference manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf), but if you're like me, you're lazy. Fortunately, we are in luck. Several kind folks have uploaded portions of the official documentation to their websites, and these can be found easily by simply Googling "x86" plus the name of the instruction mnemonic. For example, my top result for "x86 mov" is [this page](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html). Note the following section:

> **Flags affected**
>   None.

Other instructions will say different things there, of course. The `add` instruction sets virtually all of the flags, as you can see [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_5.html).

So, looking at your code, execution will begin with the flags set to meaningless, garbage values. Technically, they will contain whatever values they were last set to, but this is meaningless in the context of your program, because you did not cause them to be set to anything, and therefore cannot rely on them being set to meaningful values!

Neither the `nop` nor the `mov` instructions will affect the values of the flags, so they will continue to contain garbage values.

The flags will not contain meaningful values until the `dec` instruction is executed. Then, as per [the documentation](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_71.html), the overflow, sign, zero, adjust, and parity flags will be set according to the result of the decrement operation. The carry flag is not affected by `dec` and will therefore continue to contain a garbage value.

The [`inc` instruction](http://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_140.html) sets the flags in exactly the same way as `dec`, so the overflow, sign, zero, adjust, and parity flags will change, but the carry flag will not (and will continue to contain a garbage value).

---

I don't have a copy of the book you reference, so I don't know what it actually says. If it's just showing a dump of the register/flag state at that point in the code's execution, then the flags are just garbage values and not intended to be significant—you're supposed to focus on how the values in the registers have changed as a result of the `mov` instruction(s). If it is actually implying that the `mov` instruction sets the flags, well, then the book has a bug. :-)

Comment: I didn't know even flags can have garbage values. And yeah, the author never said anything about why AF and SF flags were set in the first place. More astonishingly, I couldn't understand how on earth AF flag would be set.

Comment: Well, they're garbage to you. Whatever code executed before yours wouldn't think they were garbage. No instruction actually sets them to garbage.